# Achieve blurred background in NSWindow with public API?

Tags: cocoa, operating-system, blur

I'm writing a Mac app and want a NSWindow to have a **semi-transparent, blurred** background (like the background of menus).

This could be achieved by using the private Apple CGS* APIs ([example](http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2008/03/using-core-image-filters-onunder.html)), but I cannot use them since it cannot get approved for the Mac App Store.

Is there any way (or hacks) that one can achieve this effect with **public** APIs?

(Making screenshots and blurring them is not feasible; user may be playing video clips in the background...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after 2 years, we have an official answer! Apple introduced `NSVisualEffectView` in OS X Yosemite, and the effect can be achieved with it :) Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 0):

I have looked hard for that, and while I cannot confirm with 100% certainty that there is no way to do that with public API (it's hard to prove a negative), I haven't found any trace of it being possible. The most “official” answer I could find is an Apple engineer [who suggested filing a feature request about it](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/216661-semi-transparent-blurred-nswindow-background.html).

Other related mailing-list threads include [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/230591-how-to-apply-coreimage-effects-to-windows.html) and [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/179525-an-idea-about-desktop-amusing.html#179525).